# Difference between maxWorkers and maxConcurrency in Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

According to Jest documentation

[--maxConcurrency](https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--maxconcurrencynum)

> Prevents Jest from executing more than the specified amount of tests at the same time. Only affects tests that use `test.concurrent`

[--maxWorkers](https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--maxworkersnumstring)

> Specifies the maximum number of workers the worker-pool will spawn for running tests

What is the relationship between these two parameters? Does the `--maxWorkers` parameter have any effect when setting `--maxConcurrency=1`? What about the opposite case - does the `--maxConcurrency` have any effect when `--maxWorkers=1` is set?

Comment: My suspicion is that -w spawns actually separate processes, while concurrency allows tests to be run concurrently in the same jest worker process. So with -w, "the OS would know", meaning also you can use "globals" etc, and they'd be slightly more expensive, while concurrency is cheaper, but your tests really have to be fully isolated even in the same node process. But that's purely a suspicion based on the options' names, not on any research.